# io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class ab.cd.ef.featuresteps

Tags: gradle, cucumber, bdd

I am getting the following error while running my feature test.

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class  ab.cd.ef.featuresteps
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
        at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:85)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:57)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$6(Runtime.java:128)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:129)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:129)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$7(Runtime.java:128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:249)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$runFeatures$3(Runtime.java:110)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:199)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.runFeatures(Runtime.java:111)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$0(Runtime.java:82)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.execute(Runtime.java:94)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:80)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <path>/CommonQueueService
        at uk.gov.di.ipvspot.integrationtests.Slice3FeatureSteps.<init>(Slice3FeatureSteps.java:30)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <path>.service.CommonQueueService
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 43 more
```

The error is also pointing to a build.gradle line  javaexec { (see below)

```
task cucumber() {
dependsOn assemble, testClasses
doLast {
    javaexec {
        mainClass = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
        classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'ab.cd.ef.featuresteps', 'src/test/features']
    }
}
```

I am using gradle 7.4.2

Does anyone know how to resolve this please? I have couple of gradle versions installed so not sure if it is due to cache-ing. I tried to delete it but couldnt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this on your project?

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/path/to/chromedriver");`

Because I had the same issue and realized that this line with the path to `chromedriver` was missed on my project.